# In App Purchase connect to real Server instead of Sandbox one?

Tags: ios, air, adobe, in-app-purchase

I tried to implement In App Purchase in my Starling game, use two following ANES:

[Freshplanet](https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-In-App-Purchase/)

[StickSports](https://github.com/StickSports/ANE-In-App-Purchase)

Nothing works till now. When I capture the traffic by Fiddler, it shows that my Ipad is trying to connect to real server(itunes.apple.com) instead of the sandbox(sandbox.itunes.apple.com).

- I uploaded a binary to itunesconnect and rejected it later.
- I tried to get product info by both full url("BunddleID.productId") and shor one("productId"), but no case gets the job done.
- I use a development certificate and provisioning file.
- I build the app in debug mode on real device(ipad ios - 5.1.1).

Can anyone help me find out the reason? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you use AppStore provisioning profile instead of AdHoc. Are you sure what you use AdHoc provisioning profile?